# call external page & load dynamic content into DIV with AJAX/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

Well, I understand there is a way to change contents within the same page using Ajax call & load functions (my example page a)
What i am looking for is, is there a way to call an external page & load dynamic content unto the selected div on that external page. i guess it possible using HTTP Request Methods
but i am really a noob at that.

OK, I have page a (picture attached)
[image]

the ajax loads the content into the "RESULT" div on clicking the specific id's 
here is the ajax script & the html i have come so far. this loads perfectly on the Result div on the "page a" itself.

```
<a href="#" id="one" /><br>
<a href="#" id="two" /><br>
<a href="#" id="three" /><br>
<div id="result"  class="functions"></div>
```

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";

    $("#one").click(function () {
    var loadUrl = "content.php";
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

    $("#two").click(function () {
    var loadUrl = "content1.php";
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

    $("#three").click(function () {
    var loadUrl = "content2.php";
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });
```

so the Query is, i have "page b" & certain buttons, on clickin the button, i want to load "page a" & load the selected content unto the result DIV.
[image]

the concept is, on page b, the id is clicked, it LOADS page a  in a new tab & loads the selected content on "RESULT" div. both pages are on the same server 
Would really appreciate any assistance or tips. thank you.

Comment: If you load whole "page a" into some tab on "page b" it will load all content of "page a" (html, body, head tags etc.). It will be a mess. So better solution is: create "page c". In "page c" you will have html, body etc., and when you need you will load "page a" and "page b" in this page (on click, on page load, whatever). Of course, do not put html, body, head tags on "page a" and "page b". In this case, you will need also `.on()` function.

Comment: @Miljan , When i mean a tab, i meant a new window. i am looking at a concept where the ajax call & load function will be made possible on a external different page also & not on the existing page only.

Comment: Oh, I see... you meant a browser tab :) It's now 5:20 AM here, so if you don't get right answer meanwhile, I'll help you when I wake up :)

Comment: Ok I would appreciate that @Miljan, thank you :)

Comment: Hi @MiljanPuzović , have you able to work around with any tips to help me work around this query...anything would be appreciated much...thanks lots :)

Comment: Hi :) Yes, I've tried, but I have much work to to, so I really don't have time, sorry. :s But my solution is based on "query strings". On "page b", out js code on eoach button to open new window. But add query string on each link. (i.e. `page_a.php?id=one`). And on "page a" put regex code to get ID value from query string. Then use that value to load content in "result" with similar code as current.

Comment: been trying to research for the concept of jquerystrings but still unable to find something revolving around the code above :/ & m kinda a noob to improvise on it :(